# How to know where a button is located

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro, this macro can be used from different worksheets through a button so it can update my data.

What I want to do is put at the end of the macro something that says "Now go back to the worksheet from where the button was pressed"

Is there a way to know which worksheet I was on when I pressed the button?

Comment: Check out [`Application.Caller`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.caller) which can provide information about how the VBA code was called. Not sure why you are getting downvoted. It's not an obvious answer and unless you know the term "caller" it's not easy to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do this.

I can put this at the very beginning of my code

```
active_sheet = ActiveSheet.Name
```

and then at the very end do this

```
Worksheets(active_sheet).Activate
```

Comment: Depending on how your code is written, you wouldn't be `Selecting` or `Activating` to move from the sheet you initiated code execution from... that may be a bigger issue based in *why* you needed this.

Comment: @Cyril I have to remove filters on one of the sheets at the beginning of my code and to do that I have to go to the sheet and select one of the cells on the table or otherwise VBA commands to remove filters sometimes don't work from my experience so that's why I had to do this on the first place.